# Failure to export query to cvs file

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to export an Access query to a cvs file. I am using the below code. "C:\MyFolder" is in the MS Access trusted locations. MS Access triggers the "Cannot update - Database or object is readonly" error. The "google.cvs" file does not exist. I expect MS Access to create the file as part of the export. What am I missing here?

```
DoCmd.TransferText _
        TransferType:=acExportDelim, TableName:="qryGoogleEarth", FileName:="C:\MyFolder\google.cvs", HasFieldNames:=blnHasFieldNames
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with code, works for me. Cannot replicate issue.